# Unable to see a newly added virtual disk in Virtualbox

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox

I am using virtualbox with

Host: Ubuntu 9.10
Guest Win 7

My old virtual disk was filing up so I added a new virtual disk. After I restarted the guest, I can not see it in the My computer. I can see a new disk in the device manager though. The new disk was added as primary slave.

What do I need to do to see it? I am guess I need to format the new virtual disk, but since I dont see any drive letter mapped to it, I am not sure of how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to prepare the disk.

Take a look at this [Microsoft guide](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Create-and-format-a-hard-disk-partition) that should walk you through what you need.  If you just need to assign a drive letter see [this guide](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Change-add-or-remove-a-drive-letter).